# Heatmap.js clickable heatmap

Tags: javascript, heatmap

Im using [Heatmap.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/index.html) to create a clickable heatmap. Im trying the following code unsuccessfully.

The legend is being displayed, but click on the canvas is not generating the heatmap like its [supposed to](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-click.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="heatmap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
// heatmap configuration
var config = {
element: document.getElementById("heatmapArea"),
radius: 30,
opacity: 50,
legend: {
position: 'br',
title: 'Example Distribution'
}
};
//creates and initializes the heatmap
var heatmap = h337.create(config);

document.getElementById("heatmapArea").onclick = function(e){
heatmap.store.addDataPoint(e.layerX, e.layerY, 1);
};
};

</script>

<div id ="heatmapArea">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their example it looks like their `div` contains a few styling definition and a class:

```
<div id="heatmapArea" class="well" style="width:610px;padding:0;height:400px;cursor:pointer;position:relative;"></div>
```

**However, you probably only need to add a `height` and `width` to your `div`.**

Here's an [**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ecshd/1/)